# Any API for azure storage account monitor configuration?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-queues

Is there any API or powershell cmdlet available for configuring the Azure stroage account for Monitoring?I mean monitoring blobs,queues and tables.

Comment: You mean configuring/viewing storage analytics?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri - Yes..

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways by which you can configure storage analytics on a storage account:

- Using Storage REST API.
- Using Storage Client Library. Look for `GetServiceProperties` and `SetServiceProperties`.
- If you're looking for a 3rd party tool, there's a free tool available from Cerebrata - http://blog.cerebrata.com/articles/2011/08/11/cerebrata-windows-azure-storage-analytics-configuration-utility-a-free-utility-to-configure-windows-azure-storage-analytics/. Using this tool, you can configure storage analytics.

If you're looking for a tool to view this data, try this tool: https://github.com/mogliang/Azure-Storage-Analytics-Viewer.